# Load JSON result in swift

Tags: json, swift, playframework

I am trying to parse JSON result obtained from Playframewordk 1.2 into swift.

Playframework result:

```
    public JsonObject getJson() {
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    if (codeJson != null) {
        for (String field : codeArticleFields) {
            if (codeJson.has(field)) {
                jsonObject.add(field, codeJson.get(field));
            }
        }
    }
    return jsonObject;
}
```

view playframework

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title:'Test' /}
#{set 'moreScripts' }
#{/set}
${product?.getJson()}
```

Here is the code of swift:

```
    func connectProductDatabase() {
    let urlString = "http://api.autoidlabs.ch/test/" + "4025089060857"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.URL = url
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler: {
        (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var error: NSError?
        if let result = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:  nil, error: &error)
            as? NSArray {
                let dataArray = result[0] as NSArray
                println(dataArray)

        } else {
            let resultString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("Flawed JSON String: \(resultString)")
        }
    })
    println("not connected")

}
```

As a result I am getting the entire file with all HTML tag. This is because it is not entering into the *if* statement. (I also tried with  options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

I tried with lot of result found from stackoverflow, but getting the same problem. If I understand well, the playframework view is not really returning a JSON, JsonObject of java is a formatted String as JSON.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.
Instead of NSArray I used NSDictionary

```
            if let result = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:  NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error)
            as? NSDictionary {
```

and then in playframework I used renderJSON instead of render.